# i need a common function for rounding login in oracle , and while inserting fields which needs to be rounded need to call this function

Tags: oracle

need your help for below scenario...

i have a interface , where i have 12 fields related to quantity & price.

my requirement is while transferring the data from staging table to interface table , i need to do rounding for these 12 fields and insert into interface table.

so , i wanted to create a common function which will do rounding. '
for all this 12 fields must refer this function to do rounding in insert statement .

Comment: If the data types in the target table are constrained, rounding will happen automatically? It isn't clear why you think you need your own function though - are you rounding rules non-standard somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you plan to insert all 12 fields as a single object i.e. serialised in JSON or as 12 separate fields. You also haven't specified the rounding you need to perform. Typically in Oracle you use either the round https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1 or trunc https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html#GUID-911AE7FE-E04A-471D-8B0E-9C50EBEFE07D function and specify the level of precision.